# Проблема с сложным выпадающим меню, как решить?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть [проект](http://all2.devruso.ru/sp/index.html) в нем сложное выпадающее меню (второй выпадающий блок по высоте выше в некоторых случаях чем первый, аналогично третий в некоторых случаях выше чем второй и т.д.), нужно поводить мышкой и все сразу станет ясно. Так вот в чем вопрос:

сейчас все как бы работает правильно, за исключением одного момента:

-если мы наводи скажем на Сухие смеси, открывается второй блок меню, все ок, но если сразу вернуться на Сухие смеси то второй блок выпадающий обрежется (поводите мышкой туда сюда и это четко видно)
[image: pic-1]
-далее переходим на второй блок пункт Штукатурки - все ок
[image: pic-2]
- но если мы вернемся на начальный первый блок - пункт Сухие смеси, то второй выпадающий блок укорачивается обрезая длинну под уровень первого блока
[image: pic-3]
выравнивание блоков я сделал с помощью вот такого скрипта

```js
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {

    hchild = $(this).children('ul').outerHeight(true) + 4;
    hparent = $(this).parents('.submenu').outerHeight(true);
    if (hchild > hparent) {
      $(this).parents('.submenu').css('height', hchild);
      if (!$(this).parent("ul").is(".level-1")) {
        $(this).parent("ul").css('height', hchild - 4);
      }
    } else {
      if (hchild < hparent) {
        $(this).children('ul').css('height', hparent - 4);


      }

    }

  },
  function() {
    $(this).parents('.submenu').removeAttr("style");
    $(this).children('ul').removeAttr("style");
    //$(this).parent("ul").removeAttr("style");
  });
```

и вот не могу понять где косяк, почему так происходит? Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что когда бы уводите мышь из второго раздела в первый сначала срабатывает `mouseOver` пункта меню "строительные смеси", потом `mouseOut` пункта меню из которого была мышь убрана. Получается, что сначала задается высота, а потом сразу-же стирается.

Лучше сделайте один обработчик события на оба события, а активное меню определяйте через селектор `:hover`

Comment: можно подробней, об одном обработчике обеих событий, а то голова уже не варит совсем